# Sublime Text 2 C Compiling

Tags: c, sublimetext2

I'm getting an odd error, when i go to build a C file 2 things happen. First, It's taking a lot longer than usual to compile a basic C file (One that's just empty). Second, when I        compile the program the output box at the bottom has lots of new lines in it so i have to scroll to the top of the output to see if their are errors. How would i go about fixing this?

here is my build system.

```
{
  "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}", "-lm", "-Wall"],
  "selector" : "source.c",
  "shell":false,
  "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: My build file is essentially the same.  I have no problems.  Do you have other compilers on your system?  What is the output of `which gcc`?

Answer (score -3):

What Operating System do you use? Linux? Using Linux is more practical, because you compile in the terminal.

Installing the Compiler 
1 - Make sure that you have the compiler installed. If you dont have, open the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) and type this and press Enter: sudo apt-get install g++ gcc build-essential

Compiling a file

1. Open the terminal and go to the local that you had saved the files.
2. Type in the terminal: gcc filename.c -o filename
3. Then, type:
4. `./filename` The program you run in the terminal normally.

PS:

gcc is for programs in .c

g++ for programs in .cpp

`-o` = to create an "executable" file

`./` = to run the program

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the OP is trying to accomplish.